# unable to install cordova using node js

Tags: windows, node.js, npm

C:\Users\admin>npm install -g cordova

---

npm WARN engine npm@1.3.4: wanted: {"node":">=0.6","npm":"1"} (current: {"node":
"0.10.33","npm":"2.1.12"})
C:\Program Files\nodejs\cordova -> C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\cordova\
bin\cordova
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\
npm-package-arg requires semver@'4' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\
semver,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.3.0
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\
read-installed\node_modules\readdir-scoped-modules requires graceful-fs@'^3.0.4'
 but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\
graceful-fs,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 3.0.2
cordova@4.1.2 C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\cordova
├── underscore@1.7.0
├── q@1.0.1
├── nopt@3.0.1 (abbrev@1.0.5)
└── cordova-lib@4.1.2 (osenv@0.1.0, properties-parser@0.2.3, bplist-parser@0.0.6
, mime@1.2.11, unorm@1.3.3, semver@2.0.11, shelljs@0.3.0, dep-graph@1.1.0, rc@0.
5.2, xcode@0.6.7, elementtree@0.1.5, d8@0.4.4, npmconf@0.1.16, tar@1.0.2, glob@4
.0.6, request@2.47.0, plist@1.1.0, npm@1.3.4, cordova-js@3.7.2)

Answer (score 0):

try to install graceful-fs:

```
npm install -g graceful-fs
```

Comment: Gives this warning:
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\
npm-package-arg requires semver@'4' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\
semver,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.3.0
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\
read-installed\node_modules\readdir-scoped-modules requires graceful-fs@'^3.0.4'
 but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\
graceful-fs,