# Node js fails to install cordova

Tags: node.js, cordova

Am trying to install cordova in windows but i keep on getting an error:
[image]

I have changed from the school wifi to a personal modem without any proxy configurations but still the same problem.
I used it to install ionic and just worked fine but the problem is cordova

This is my npm-debug.log

[image]

I have also tried installing graceful-fs: as pointed out in:
[unable to install cordova using node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27461386/unable-to-install-cordova-using-node-js) 
but still the problem is isnt solved
This is my proxy configurations in windows 10
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to setup the proxy settings https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/issues-installing-cordova-behind-proxy-error-using-npm-install/27294/2

```
npm config set proxy http://user:password@url:port
npm config set https-proxy http://user:password@url:port
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

Make sure your username + password are correct.

Comment: Am not on an internet with proxy settings. I have updated the question with my proxy config..they are off

Comment: I had a friend come across this issue, it had something todo with the proxy. Althought I cannot remember exactly how it was fixed...Just try searching around google. @GEOFFREYMWANGI

Comment: ill try your ans when connected to a proxy network..The user in the (http://user) is it the network address...

Comment: I asked another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37176949/setting-up-proxy-from-an-address-in-nodejs  You can check it please