# Setting up proxy from an address in nodejs

Tags: node.js

Suppose one is on a network address and these are the credentials:

```
Address: 172.a.b.c
Port:8080
Password:abcd
```

Am trying to set up node js where one is required to set up proxy:

```
npm config set proxy http://user:password@url:port
npm config set https-proxy http://user:password@url:port
```

Can someone help me in how will i add my address and password to the

```
 npm config set....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking? You're are asking how you attach your user + password to the npm configuration right? If so, this should help you:

```
npm config set proxy http://YOUR_USERNAME_HERE:YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE@url:YOUR_PORT_HERE

npm config set proxy-https http://YOUR_USERNAME_HERE:YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE@url:YOUR_PORT_HERE
```

It may end up looking like this

```
npm config set proxy http://james:jamesIsCool@url:3000
```

Comment: Oh and remember to put your url in there, just after the @ symbol, replace url with your address.

Comment: Is the username and password the local computer name and password or network credentials...